# why windows x64 home space simplifies support of C unprototyped functions and C/C++ vararg functions

Tags: 64-bit, calling-convention

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

In the link above, there is following statement:

The caller is responsible for allocating space for parameters to the callee, and must always allocate sufficient space for the 4 register parameters, even if the callee doesn’t have that many parameters. This aids in the simplicity of supporting C unprototyped functions, and vararg C/C++ functions.

Can anyone explain why the home space can simplify support of C unprototyped functions and vararg C/C++ functions?

Thanks.